# How to work with multiple insert queries?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to know how to work around multiple queries inserting values in different table in same database.

So far I have added one and it is working but I don't understand how to add and third and so on in different tables.

```
require 'db/connect.php';
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $age = trim($_POST['age']);



    $insert= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO data (age, name, created) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
    $insert->bind_param('is', $age, $name);

    if($insert->execute()){
        echo 'record added';
        die();

    }
```

This is how I tried two of them

```
$name= $_SESSION['team'];
$id = $_SESSION['id']; 
$cname1= trim($_POST['coachname1']);
$cname2= trim($_POST['coachname2']);


$team = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO team (team_name, time_registered)VALUES(?, NOW())");
$team->bind_param('s', $name);
$team->execute();

$insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO coach( team_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?, ?)");
$insert->bind_param('ss', $cname1, $cname2);


    if($insert->execute()){

    echo 'record added';
    }
```

Two values are carried to this page by session: I am registering team where I have coach and players until now I am just trying to add team name, team id is auto increment and in coach table I am adding first name last name and team id to relate him to team. This is just now working and code above adding one statement is working perfectly .

Comment: If you post what you have tried ASAP.

Comment: it is testing query that i did for multi page registration process in the end i want to insert fields in different tables.

Comment: Why not create another query and execute that for the different table?

Answer (score 0):

> i dont understand how to add and third and so on in different tables

Just add them one by one.

If you have all these tables of same structure - then make a single table out of them all first.